# Trying to access dropdowns option text value using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

In HTML, I have a dropdown and I am trying to access the options text.

```
<select>
<option value="0">Please Select Location</option>
<option value="1">London</option>
<option value="2">Paris</option>
<option value="3">Tokyo</option>
<option value="4">Maimi</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to access `Maimi` using a jQuery function. But I am not getting the way to resolve it.

Comment: You posted the question and answer within one minute ???!!!

Comment: As I posted the question, in suggested links I got the reference and at the same time I stick the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got the answer :

```
$("#dropdownid option:selected").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#yourSelectId').change(function() {
        $('#yourSelectId option:selected').html();
    });
});
```